# How to format text with gq by cutting long lines but without joining shorter lines?

Tags: formatting, textwidth

I don't understand what shall I set (I guess `fo`, but how?) for cutting lines that are longer than `textwidth` but without joining lines that are shorter.

For example, assume that I have `textwidth` option set to 78 and I have the following text:

```
This text is just an example to show what I want to achieve. 

However, I am failing in that and therefore I am asking for help.
Let's add a random enumerated list to make the example more complete.

    1. frog
    2. cow
    3. donkey

And let me add another line, just to make something more complete.
Now, let me add a very long line that it is not formatted at all and I want to cut it happened to be way too long

Hello,
My name
Is John Nash
```

If I type `gggqG`, I have the following:

```
This text is just an example to show what I want to achieve. 

However, I am failing in that and therefore I am asking for help.  Let's add a
random enumerated list to make the example more complete.

    1. frog 2. cow 3. donkey

And let me add another line, just to make something more complete.  Now, let
me add a very long line that it is not formatted at all and I want to cut it
happened to be way too long

hello My name Is John Nash
```

but what I want instead is the following:

```
This text is just an example to show what I want to achieve. 

However, I am failing in that and therefore I am asking for help.
Let's add a random enumerated list to make the example more complete.

    1. frog
    2. cow
    3. donkey

And let me add another line, just to make something more complete.  Now, let
me add a very long line that it is not formatted at all and I want to cut it
happened to be way too long

Hello,
My name
Is John Nash
```

Namely, I want that longer lines than `textwidth` are cut, but shorter lines are left untouched.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried `set fo=tc`

Comment: The list could probably be solved with formatoptions or comments, but the last paragraph is trickier for automatic solutions.

Comment: That's not trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do:

```
:g/^.\{80\}/normal gqq
```

Or more generic as suggested by @Barzi2002

```
:execute 'g/^.\{' .. &textwidth ..'\}/normal gqq'
```

Comment: Very smart and elegant! I would just substitute 80 with &textwidht somehow  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have adapted the code to take into account the `textwidth`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `w` to the default value of `'formatoptions'` gives you the desired behavior:

```
:set formatoptions+=w
```

You shouldn't have stopped trying at set `fo=tc`. `:help fo-t` and `:help fo-c` are not related to the problem at hand… and `:help fo-w` is a few lines below.